# specifying a comparator

Tags: java

i have a homework where i am supposed to to throw an exception if a comparator was specified. what does it mean to specify a comparator

Answer (score 0):

Some constructors and methods accept an optional comparator argument. I'm guessing that you have to override and check if the argument isn't null and throw IllegalArgumentException or such.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but one example is a data structure such as a `TreeSet`. It can use the natural ordering of the objects inserted, or one can provide a separate `Comparator` to its constructor which it will user for ordering its elements.

Comment: actually i am to write an add method to add items to an arrayList which i can do, but then it says if a comparator is specified i am to throw an UnsupportedOperationException. i am not exactly sure where or how the comparator is to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think throwing Exception is needed. Comparator just takes care compare two Objects order, why do we need to throw Exception when compare?